# Will gaming performance improve if i upgrade my graphic card?

Tags: graphics-card

I have this inside my computer:CPU - 2 quad q9950 2.83ghz ,ram - 4GB,
motherboard - gigabyte ep43c-ds3 and power supply 504 WATT
so i was going for NVIDIA gtx 650 ti and i was wondering if it is worth it only updating my video card ,will it significantly improve game performance? 
current video card nvidia geforce 9800 gt

Comment: What is it replacing? What type of games?

Comment: it is replacing nvidia geforce 9800 gt.and games that i am playing now are:assassin's creed 3,farcry 3 ,COD black ops 2,dead space 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes.  The GTX 650ti scores ~4x better on the Passmark G3D Mark score.  See this [chart](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu_list.php) and search for the two cards.

This is no guarantee, but the 650ti is 6 generations newer and *should* be significantly better.